# I want my code to print the frequency of characters in the order of appearance of string

Tags: c

My code is printing the frequency of characters in random order. What can be done so that it prints the frequency of characters in order in which the word is given. My current code is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main() {
    char string1[50];
    int i = 0, counter[26] = { 0 };
    printf("\nEnter a string\n");
    //Inputs a string
    gets(string1);
    while (string1[i] != '\0') {
        //checks and includes all the characters 
        if (string1[i] >= 'a' && string1[i] <= 'z') {
            //counts the frequency of characters
            counter[string1[i] - 'a']++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    //printing frequency of each character     
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (counter[i] != 0)
            printf("%c occurs %d times.\n", i + 'a', counter[i]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

sample output:

[image: currently getting output]

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  Are you saying that the code works correctly, except that it skips the first character in the string?

Comment: It is not printing the frequency of first character in the string.Other than that it prints all the character in the string

Comment: Show us some sample input, the actual output, and the expected output.

Comment: Your edit shows the code working as expected.  The input string `hello` contains 1 `e`, 1 `h`, 2 `l`, and 1 `o`, which is what is printed.  So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I want it to print in order.1st character- its occurence,2nd character-its occurence,3rd character-its occurence and so on

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues in your code:

- you use `gets`: this function is unsafe, it was removed from the current version of the C Standard.
- you increment `i` only for if `string1[i]` is a lowercase letter: you will run an infinite loop if you type any other character.
- the proper prototype for `main` is either `int main(void)` or `int main(int arc, char *argv[])`.
- you only count lower case letters.  `H` is upper case, thus not counted.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    char string1[128];
    int i = 0, counter[256] = { 0 };
    printf("\nEnter a string\n");
    //Inputs a string
    if (fgets(string1, sizeof string1, stdin) == NULL) {
        // empty file: got an empty line
        *string1 = '\0';
    }
    for (i = 0; string1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (isalpha((unsigned char)string1[i])) {
            //counts the frequency of letters
            counter[string1[i]]++;
        }
    }
    //printing frequency of each counted character
    //characters are printed in the order of appearance
    for (i = 0; string1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (counter[string1[i]] != 0) {
            printf("%c occurs %d times.\n",
                   string1[i], counter[string1[i]]);
            counter[string1[i]] = 0;   // print each letter once.
        }
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I updated to code to print the letters in order of appearance, without duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the characters printed in order of their appearance by using the string a second time to generate the output.

In your section where you are "printing the frequency of each character", use the code to process the input string. This time, if the frequency value is not zero, print it and then reset the frequency value to zero. If the frequency value *is* zero, you must have already printed it so do nothing.

```
//printing frequency of each counted character (in input order)
for (i = 0; string1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    char ch = string[i];
    if (counter[ch - 'a'] != 0) {
        printf("%c occurs %d times.\n", ch, counter[ch - 'a']);
        counter[ch - 'a'] = 0;
    }
}
```